# Is it possible to store an array of hashes in a cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

Note: I don't have the option to use the session variable for what I need to do.

I'm looking to store multiple 'vote' hashes in one cookie. Where a vote would look like so:

```
vote = {c_id, lv_id, wv_id}
```

So, something like

```
cookies[:votes] = [vote1, vote2, vote3]
```

Is something like this possible in rails? Or will I have to store each individual vote as its own cookie? Thanks

Comment: beware of cookie overflow

Comment: Syntax wrong on `vote`, not Hash, not Array. Possible but ugly if it's for persistent stuff like vote. Also risk cookie overflow for max size is 4k.

Comment: `cookies[:votes] = [vote1, vote2, vote3]` is entirely valid.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible. Here is an example.  For more check the link

```
# Assign an array of values to a cookie.
cookies[:lat_lon] = [47.68, -122.37]

# Sets a cookie that expires in 1 hour.
cookies[:login] = { value: "XJ-122", expires: 1.hour.from_now }
```

[ActionDispatch::Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html)